# I'm making an HTML form and I need to save checkbox information in the database but this information also needs to be searchable. Best possible way?

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, forms

So I am designing a database and I have an entity called 'resources', which, has standard attributes like name, url, email that fit nicely into the database schema (as varchars and text data types). However, these resources have other attributes that need to be represented in an HTML form as checkboxes, meaning that they can take on more than one value depending on the number of checkboxes checked, but also need to searchable. In fact, the requirements state that most of these resource attributes need to be searchable and that's fine for the varchar and text column types but I don't know what to do for these attributes that can take on more than one value from a set of values (the attributes represented as checkboxes.)

Here's an example of what I mean:

**Resource Topics**

*Please choose the topics for this resource:*

- Recycling
- Reducing
- Reusing
- Composting
- Landfill

So here, the resource attribute is the resource topic and for this resource record if a user checks
Recycling, Reusing and Landfill then I have to store this info in the database record, yet, it has to be searchable meaning if the user queries 'recycling', 'reusing' or 'landfill' then the aforementioned record will be returned.

By the way, I have to do this in PHP and MySQL. So, I have tried serializing the checkboxes with PHP and storing them as serialized strings, however, these are not very searchable because I get inconsistent results when I write MySQL queries that try to match terms using "LIKE". I suspect this has to do with the way that PHP serializes arrays. So I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this. Would storing the data as JSON encoded strings be a better way of doing this?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest one column per checkbox. They can be of type boolean if you do some mapping in your php code.

Comment: I thought about this but I'm looking at, at least, 40 columns if I do that I was just wondering if there was a better and more efficient way of doing this. It looks like I might do that as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write custom logic to get this search to work. If you are doing this in a stored procedure, you might have something like:

```
Select * from resource
Where name like '%' + @query + '%'
And (IsRecycling = 1 and 'recycling' like '%' + @query + '%')
[rest of your and statements will be identical to above and listed here]
```

Disclaimer: this code is not tested, but here to demonstrate a general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using a string in which each character represents whether or not a checkbox has been ticked or not.

Example:

```
<?php
 $checkboxes = array ('Recycling',
                      'Reducing',
                      'Reusing',
                      'Composting',
                      'Landfill',
                       // etc.
                      );

 $string = ''; // the string that holds whether or not a checkbox is ticked
 foreach($checkboxes as $checkbox_id=>$checkbox_name)
     $string .= $_POST[$checkbox_name]?1:0;

 // example mySQL
 $update_query = "UPDATE `table` SET `checkbox_data` = '$string'";
 $select_query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE SUBSTRING(`checkbox_data`,$checkbox_id,1) == 1"; 
?>
```

Disadvantages are if you need to often make changes to the list of checkboxes - doing so can get confusing, but isn't an insurmountable problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the Resource Entity could have more then one topic (Recycling, Reducing, etc). If so, why not a many-to-many relationship between Resource and Resource_topic ? This way, you can search topics, which are marked/belong to 'Recycling', 'Reducing' or 'Whatever'